# asp webform url rewriting to asp mvc routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a asp.net webform project that i converting it to MVC.

in webform, I have some urls that created by url rewriting :

me.com/find/?item=5 **rewrite to** me.com/item-5/

Now, I want to create this (me.com/item-5/) routing in MVC.

I created it :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Item",
            url: "Find/Item-{ID}/",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Default",
                action = "Find",
                ID = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

but it didn't work.

**Attention**

I don't want this :

me.com/Item/5/

Comment: Please provide details which controller is not working & what action method you have problem with. Also provide any error encountered on debug.

Comment: the error is "Not Found Page"

Comment: Try using a regex route constraint and see if it works: `constraints: new { ID: @"(\d+)" }` (assumed ID is item number).